# Flutter: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0:

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart, dio

I am getting this error in dio library while calling local API

```
Flutter: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Causing issue:-**

My base url is without **http:// or https//** causing the issue **10.0.2.2:4003/api/v1/**

**Worked for me :-**

I only added **http://** in URL **http://10.0.2.2:4003/api/v1/**

you can use **https//** instead of **http//**

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such error it's better to define baseUrl while instantiating Dio.

```
var dio = Dio(); // with default Options

// Set default configs
dio.options.baseUrl = 'https://www.xx.com/api';


// or new Dio with a BaseOptions instance.
var options = BaseOptions(
baseUrl: 'https://www.xx.com/api',
 );
Dio dio = Dio(options);
```